# Update magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.6 with composer

Tags: magento, composer-php

As mentioned in the official magento 2 upgrade guide I installed magento/composer-root-update-plugin with the command:

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
```

but when I run the command

```
composer update
```

it gives me this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/composer-root-update-plugin, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

How i can solve?

EDIT -----------

this is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "magento/magento2ce",
"description": "Magento 2 (Open Source)",
"type": "project",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": true
    }
},
"version": "2.4.3",
"require": {
    "php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
   [...]
    "magento/composer": "1.6.0",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": ">=0.1.11",
    "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.2",
    [...]
},


[..]
    "require-dev": {
        [...]
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    }
    [...]
    }
```

My composer version is 2.5.5 and PHP version: 7.4.33 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: "It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it" - can you share the `composer.json`? Does it include Magento's repository?

Comment: @NicoHaase where can I find the custom repository? I added the file composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package might be part of Magento's own repository. Add it to your composer.json like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Have a look at [their documentation](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/authentication-keys.html) if you have more questions about this repository

Answer (score -1):

Try Your composer.json as below line , I solved this way

```
"require-dev": {
 "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1", to ==> "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The composer.json from the question doesn't even contain a requirement of v2.5.2